# How to use yield to return an error (from catch error)

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

My service `_session` try to log in and return `true` if succeed or an error message from `catchError` if fail. I would like to yield this message and so, call `yield` from the catch block, but it's not possible, so I did:

Will this work as I expected or is there another way to do this?

```
@override
  Stream<DgState> mapEventToState(DgEvent event) async* {
    if (event is LoginDgEvent) {
      yield LoadingState();
      String errMessage;

      bool hasLogged = await _session
          .login(event.userCredential.login, event.userCredential.password)
          .catchError((err) {
            errMessage = err;
      });

      yield LoginState(hasLogged ? 'Ok': errMessage);

    }
  }
```

Comment: An error happens but `errMessage` is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a event for update state.

```
 @override
  Stream<DgState> mapEventToState(DgEvent event) async* {
    //Event for update state
    if(event is LoginUpdateStateEvent){
      yield event.state;
    }

    if (event is LoginDolceGustoEvent) {
      yield LoadingState();
      String errMessage;

      bool hasLogged = await _session
          .login(event.userCredential.login, event.userCredential.password)
          .catchError((err) {
            //dispatch
            dispatch(LoginUpdateStateEvent(state:LoginErrorState(errMessage)));
      });

      yield LoginState(hasLogged ? 'Ok': errMessage);

    }
  }
```